# Thread safety for static variables

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
class ABC implements Runnable {
    private static int a;
    private static int b;
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

I have a Java class as above. I have multiple threads of this class. In the `run()` method, the variables `a` & `b` are incremented each for several times. On each increment, I am putting these variables in a Hashtable.

Hence, each thread will increment both variables and putting them in Hashtable. How can I make these operations thread safe?

Comment: @Frozen Spider @Bohemian @Nim in book java se 7 programmer exam 804 can some one explain to me  `public void run() { synchronized(SharedCounter.class) { SharedCounter.count++; } }` However, this code is inefficient since it acquires and releases the lock every time just to increment the value of count.

Comment: @shareef Comments are not for asking questions. Instead, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Bohemian here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463440/thread-safety-static-variables

Answer (score 12):

I would use [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which is designed to be thread-safe and is dead easy to use and imparts the absolute minimal of synchronization overhead to the application:

```
class ABC implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger a;
    private static AtomicInteger b;
    public void run() {
        // effectively a++, but no need for explicit synchronization!
        a.incrementAndGet(); 
    }
}

// In some other thread:

int i = ABC.a.intValue(); // thread-safe without explicit synchronization
```

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what needs to be thread-safe. For these `int` primitives, you'll need either to replace them with `AtomicInteger`'s or only operate with them within `synchronized` method or block. If you need to make your cross-thread Hashtable thread-safe, you don't need to do anything, as it already is synchronized.

Comment: Making an int volatile does not make an increment operation atomic. It does enable the use of an AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater

Comment: Thank you, it seems, that I myself had a wrong understanding of `volatile`. Corrected the answer.

Comment: In other words, static fields are not thread safe. Only final fields are thread safe. For both instance and static fields that are not final, you have to access them within synchronized methods/statements or using the concurrent lock feature available in Java 7/8.

Comment: No, that's not exactly the idea. Being static or final have nothing to do with thread safety. Sure, `final int` will be thread-safe just because it will be immutable - simply making mutable object (such as `ArrayList`) to be `final` won't magically make it thread-safe. Making its getter synchronized won't help either. You'll have to proxy and synchronize all of instances wishful public methods without providing access to the instance itself.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `synchronized` method, e.g.

```
public synchronized void increment()
{
  a++; b++;
  // push in to hash table.
}
```

The above is good if you are accessing the statics through a single instance, however if you have multiple instances, then you need to synchronize on some static object - something like (untested)..

```
private static Object lock = new Object();
```

in the method

```
public void increment()
{
  synchronize(lock)
  {
    a++;b++;
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

NOTE: These approaches assume that you want to increment `a` and `b` in one *atomic* action, the other answers highlight how they can be *individually* incremented using atomics.

Comment: would it not be necessary to synchronize at the class level rather than the object level?

Comment: @mcfinnigan - correct, I was assuming that access was through a single instance...

Comment: you can also synchronize directly against the Class object if you need to: `synchronize(ABC.class) { ... }`

Comment: @mcfinnigan - it's been a while since I touched java, so a little rusty! :)

Comment: haha, no worries.  I use it every day and I forget basic stuff all the time!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add some details about the answer to this question.

Firstly, the OP is asking about :

> How can I make these operations thread safe?

Before answer this question, we need to reach the consistency about what is **thread safe**. The definition I like mostly is that from "Java Concurrency In Practice" and it's

> A  class  is  thread safe  if  it  behaves  correctly  when  accessed 
>   from  multiple  threads,  regardless  of  the  scheduling  or 
>   interleaving  of  the  execution  of  those  threads  by  the  runtime
>   environment,  and  with  no  additional  synchronization  or  other
>   coordination on the part of the calling code.

If you agree with the definition, it means we reach the consistency before further discussion. Let's return to the operations you meant, it's `a++` and `b++`, after the increment, you will put them into a `HashTable`.

For the `a++` operation, it's not really a single operation. It obeys the model of **read modify write**. As you can see, it actually contains three individual steps. Read the value, add one to it and save it back. If you have two threads read the variable `a` with value `1` at the same time, after the modifications and save back operations. The value will be `2`, but it actually should be `3`. To avoid this situation happen, like what others have suggested, you can use `AtomicInteger` instead of `int` type directly. The `AtomicInteger` will guarantee some operations like increment to execute atomically. That means, the **read modify write** operations can't be divided and will be executed as one individual step.
After that, the OP wants to save the value into a HashTable. The HashTable is a thread safe container, no other synchronization needed.
Hope this clarification can help someone in other way. Thanks.