# Thread safety static variables

Tags: java, thread-safety

i read
[thread safety for static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442559/thread-safety-for-static-variables?noredirect=1#comment39734527_7442559) and i understand it and i agree with it but

In book java se 7 programmer exam 804 can some one explain to me

```
public void run() { 
    synchronized(SharedCounter.class) { 
        SharedCounter.count++; 
    }
}
```

> However, this code is inefficient since it acquires and releases the
> lock every time just to increment the value of count.

can someone explain to me the above quote

Comment: to put it simple what confuses me in the above code ... "the synchronized block on a class does it make the static variables of it safe from datarace ?"

Comment: What makes it safe is to *always* access the shared count variable using a synchronized block, and to always use the *same* object as monitor. Whether this monitor is `SharedCounter.class` or any other object doesn't change anything.

Comment: why the down vote so i can know next time what i did wrong thankx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not particularly inefficient. It could be slightly more efficient. The main problem is that it is fragile: if any developer forgets to synchronize its access to the global `SharedCounter.count` variable, you have a thread-safety issue. Indeed, since `i++` is not an atomic operation and since changing the value of a variable without synchronization doesn't make the variables new value visible to other threads, Every access to `i` must be done in a synchronized way.

The synchronization is thus not correctly encapsulated in a single class. Generally, accessing global public fields is bad design. It's even worse in a multi-threaded environment.

Using an AtomicInteger solves the encapsulation problem, and makes it slightly more efficient at the same time.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `i++` is not an atomic operation, so it *needs* synchronization. It's just that this serializes on the class, so any other blocks synch'd on the class, or static synch'd methods would block too.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing can be expensive, so it shouldn't be used carelessly. There are better ways such as using `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet();` which uses different mechanisms to handle the synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

It's inefficient compared to using intrinsic CPU instructions which can do atomic increments without using a lock. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html